# how to change nls_language in nls_instance_parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, nls

Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0) database

Issue: I wanted to change `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` in `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS`. I know how to change for session, but I wanted to change it for the instance. The reason why is because stored procedure scripts weren't running correctly due to timestamp. I was getting this error:

```
start_date=>TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('12-MAY-2015 02.00.00.000000000 AM +05:30','DD-MON-RRRR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=english'), repeat_interval=>
ORA-01855: E necessario AM/A.M. ou PM/P.M.
```

Reasononing: The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` were the same across. I even tried `unset LANG` and `unset NLS_LANG`. Despite all of this I was still getting date conversion errors, so I decided to update all of the NLS-related parameters to the same values across all views. My database (nls_database_parameters) and session (nls_session_parameters) were showing the same NLS_LANGUAGE, but my instance (nls_instance_parameters) was not.

Solution: To fix this I had to update the `init<db>.ora` and the `spfiles<db>.ora`
I didn't really see this explicitly specified anywhere except for maybe on Burleson Consulting's [website](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pfile_spfile.htm), so I decided to put my findings here to help others with the same issue.

I updated `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` in `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS`, restarted the database, and it fixed my issue.

I had to force restart because for some reason I couldn't restart normally.

Comment: I think the main purpose of `NLS_LANGUAGE`, `NLS_TERRITORY`, etc. (except CHARACTERSET) on database, resp. instance level is just to provide **default** values for according session level values which in fact apply. Fix the problem in your session, resp. in your code.

Comment: Show us your actual problem - changing NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_TERRITORY in NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS is most likely the wrong solution!

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit ! It did seem weird that NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_TERRITORY were affecting my date conversions, but after changing NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS my issue was resolved. I added more details about my issue in the description. Overall I added this question to show people how to update this because I didn't see it easily explained anywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example below on how to update this:

```
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ unset LANG
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 27 13:18:26 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SELECT sys_context('userenv','language') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','LANGUAGE')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.AL32UTF8

SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ unset NLS_LANG
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 27 13:18:51 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SELECT sys_context('userenv','language') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','LANGUAGE')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.AL32UTF8

SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
```

This is where I edited the init and spfile - you might want to take a backup !!

```
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ ls
hc_scpp.dat  init.ora  initscpp.ora  lkSCPP  orapwmydb  spfilemydb.ora  teste.ora
```

edit initscpp.ora and spfilemydb.ora with the values you want for the NLS parameters
Then I proceeded to restart

```
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 27 13:25:30 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> shutdown
^CORA-01013: o usuario solicitou o cancelamento da operac?o atual
```

shutdown was slow so I [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>] and tried to force restart then restart normally !!

```
SQL> startup force
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2,0724E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                  3158000 bytes
Variable Size            3070230544 bytes
Database Buffers         1,7645E+10 bytes
Redo Buffers                5230592 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> shutdown
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2.0724E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                  3158000 bytes
Variable Size            3070230544 bytes
Database Buffers         1.7645E+10 bytes
Redo Buffers                5230592 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@mydbserver dbs]$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 27 13:31:17 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>  SELECT sys_context('userenv','language') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','LANGUAGE')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```